# issues when going to www vs not going to www

Tags: javascript, web

I'm working on my dev box and noticing that I'm having issues when I go to `www.host.com` vs `host.com`.

Specifically, I had a javascript hover effect that isn't being applied when I go to `www.host.com` however it works when i go to `host.com`.

My thoughts are that its a problem with the server and when I merge to live it will resolve itself however I am not quite sure if thats really the solution.

Has anyone ever experienced this and what should I do?

Comment: Can you share this specific javascript code that doesn't work?

Comment: You are going to have problems with both unless you also include the protocol (http:// or https://).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your JavaScript code in both of domain (www.host.com and host.com) because the browser usually will cache your JavaScript files to make it load the page fast rather than always take from the server. If you want to clear the cache, you can try to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

More over, to easily make your JavaScript code updated automatically when you deploy your new code in JavaScript, try versioning your JavaScript files (i.e. `myCode_v_2_0_1.js`) to force the browser to load new JavaScript source.